# On a finite lattice, I define an equivalence relation based on automorphisms, and want to determine if the quotient set is a lattice.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, equivalence-relations

Let $(L,\land, \lor)$ be a finite lattice. I consider the relation $\approx$ on L defined by $x \approx y$ iff there exists an automorphism $h$ on $L$ such that $h(x) = y$. $\approx$ is an equivalence relation. I note $|a|$ the equivalence class of an element $a$ of L.
Is it true that for a,b,c,d in $L^4$, if $a \approx b$ and $c \approx d$, then $a \land b \approx c \land d$? If this is the case, can I conclude that the quotient set $L/\approx$ is a lattice, by defining $|a| \land |b| = |a \land b|$?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't work. Consider the six-element lattice $\{0,x,y,u,w,1\}$ with $0\le x\le y\le 1$ and $0\le u\le w\le 1$ (and no other inequalities other than those required by the foregoing). Then in this lattice we have $x\approx x$ (trivially) and $y\approx w$ but $$x\vee y=y\not\approx 1=x\vee w.$$ Re: your notation, I'm here taking $a=b=x$, $c=y$, $d=w$. (Incidentally, I think there's a typo in the initial question you ask: you don't want to compare $a\vee b$ and $c\vee d$ but $a\vee c$ and $b\vee d$.)

In general, the orbit relation on a structure is rarely a congruence, since even if $a_i\approx b_i$ for $i\in I$ we may not have a single automorphism $f$ with $f(a_i)=b_i$ simultaneously for all $i\in I$. ([This old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4297141/what-happens-when-we-partition-g-into-equivalence-classes-induced-by-its-automor/4297143#4297143) treats another case of this.)

Comment: It might (in my opinion) be that the OP doesn't understand your reasoning since you use $a$ in both sides. This is, of course, because $a \approx a$.

Comment: @amrsa Good catch, I wrote that poorly. Fixed!

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Frankly I should have seen this by myself before bothering the community, sorry about it. Now, even though this relation is not a congruence, the quotient set can be ordered and appears to be a lattice - in this example, the chain {0} < {x,u} < {y,w} <1 . Is it generally the case for a finite lattice, or can you think of counterexamples as well?

Comment: @ycras Admittedly the following is an infinite lattice, but it's still instructive in my opinion: consider the linear order $$\left(\bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}(2z,2z+1)\right)\cup \left(\mathbb{Q}\cap \bigcup_{z\in\mathbb{Z}}(2z+1,2z+2)\right)$$ (the ordering is the usual one on real numbers). Basically, this looks like an alternating pattern of $\mathbb{Q}$s and $\mathbb{R}$s. It has two "automorphism types" of elements, but there's no reasonable way to say that one is above the other.

Comment: That said, in the finite case there **is** something natural you can do: if $\approx$ is the automorphism orbit relation on a lattice $L$ and $X,Y$ are $\approx$-classes, say $X\trianglelefteq Y$ iff $$\forall y\in Y\exists x\in X(x\le_Ly).$$ This is always transitive, and as long as $L$ is finite it will also be asymmetric (consider the above example to see why finiteness is important). However, I don't think it will always yield a lattice.

Comment: @NoahSchweber - Thank you. This is indeed the order I'm considering for ≈-classes, and it works well in the finite case. Now I'm wondering  if (or in which cases) it's yeilding a lattice ; In my question I had missed the fact that the equivalence is obviously not a congruence, so I can't go that route. By the way, I have the same question with the following equivalence:  x ≈ y iff L\{x} is isomorphic (as a poset) to L\{y}. If I'm not mistaken the former implies the latter. But this more general equivalence is not a congruence either...